# how to binary fan out

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I want to fan out binary data like in the following examples:

```
8 bit to 16 bit: 
     0 0 0 1   0 0 0 1  (0x11)    becomes 
    0000 0011 0000 0011 (0x0303)

8 bit to 32 bit: 
       0    1    0    0    0    1    1    0 (0x46)       becomes 
    0000 1111 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 0000 (0x0F000FF0)

16 to 32 bit: 
     0 0 0 1   0 0 1 1   0 1 1 1   1 1 1 1  (0x137F)     becomes 
    0000 0011 0000 1111 0011 1111 1111 1111 (0x030F3FFF)
```

Since this question is tagged with `bit-manipulation`, I am looking for a compact solution without any loops or additional variables needed. The code should also be platform independent, so inline assembly is not what I want either.

This may be a duplicate question, but I have no idea how to search for it. Most certainly there is a proper name for what I want to do, but I just don't know it.

**EDIT:**
To clarify some of your comments, here is a list of methods the solution should **not** contain:

- assembly code (platform dependent)
- 'complex' computation like loops (that's why I tagged this question with `bit-fiddling`)
- additional runtime variables (e.g. helper constants, look up tables, ...)

Since you asked for it, here are some further details on my use case: I'm working on embedded platforms (microcontrollers) and want to mask registers. This specific case is about IO registers, where I have 16 pads for each port and several port registers to configure the pads. Some of these configuration registers use 2 bits per pad, some 4 bits. So if I want to mask individual pads when accessing the registers I need to mask those registers accordingly.

Let's say I have two configuration registers and want to access pads 4 and 8:

```
uint32_t configreg_2perpad;       // the first configuration register
uint32_t configreg_4perpad_low;   // lower half of the second configuration register
uint32_t configreg_4perpad_high;  // higher half of the second configuration register

uint8_t pad4 = 3;                 // we start counting at 0, of course
uint8_t pad8 = 7;
uint16_t pad_mask = (1 << pad4) |
                    (1 << pad8);  // this is now 0x0088
```

So what I am looking for now is a bit-wise manipulation of `pad_mask` so I get according masks for the registers, which would be

```
uint32_t configreg_2perpad_mask = 0x0000C0C0;
uint32_t configreg_4perpad_low_mask = 0xF000F000;
uint32_t configreg_4perpad_high_mask = 0x00000000;
```

Obviously, since memory (both RAM and flash) is a very scarce resource on µCs, I would prefer a solution without the need for further static variables like look up tables (waste of RAM) or static functions (waste of flash).

Comment: is that "16 to 32 bit" example correct?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the operation you are trying to perform? Or how the transformation works?

Comment: I was literally pasting in the answer when this question got closed.  Can we re-open?

Comment: To be clear, are you wanting each bit to turn into multiple bits, like a string manipulation that repeats every character?

Comment: You can use the same idea as [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveBMN), to interleave a 16-bit int with zero bits. You only need the `x` part: `x = (x | (x << S[3])) & B[3]; x = (x | (x << S[2])) & B[2]; x = (x | (x << S[1])) & B[1]; x = (x | (x << S[0])) & B[0];`. Then, to duplicate the bits, simply multiply `x` by `0b11`. This should give the right answer. From 8 to 32 bits: interleave with zero bits twice, and multiply by `0b1111`.

Comment: Note that on x86, with BMI2, you can do something like `r =  _pdep_u32(x, 0x55555555); r = r * 0b11;`, which compiles to only 2 instructions. But, obviously, this is not platform independent, which you required. Moreover it is slow on AMD (but fast on Intel).

Comment: Although, for the 8-bit to 32-bit case, it is more efficient to adapt the arrays `B` and `S`, instead of interleaving twice with zero bits. For 8 -> 32 only three steps of `x = (x | (x << S[i])) & B[i];` are needed.

Comment: Have you considered a lookup table?

Comment: @wim Nice answer! I tried it and it perfectly does its job. However, I've decided for the method proposed by selbie, since it is slightly more efficient in my case.

Comment: @Thargon That is very surprising. Maybe the multiplication is expensive on your platform? You can avoid it easily, which is shown by [user3386109's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52339020/2439725) answer.

Comment: @wim: I decided for selbies solution because of the smaller lookup table (16 vs 20 bytes). However, user3386109's answer is probably as fast as it can get for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fanning 8 bits to 16 can be done in a few lines of code:

```
uint16_t n = 0x11;
n = (n | (n << 4)) & 0x0f0f;
n = (n | (n << 2)) & 0x3333;
n = (n | (n << 1)) & 0x5555;
n = (n | (n << 1));
printf("0x%04x\n", n);  // prints 0x0303
```

Here's how it works. Start with the 8 bits in a 16-bit variable:

```
0000 0000 abcd efgh     // letters a to h represent the bits of the 8-bit number
```

Shift left by 4 bits and OR: `n = n | (n << 4)`

```
0000 abcd ???? efgh     // bits with a '?' are garbage we don't want
```

Mask off the garbage: `n = n & 0x0f0f`

```
0000 abcd 0000 efgh
```

Shift left by 2 bits and OR: `n = n | (n << 2)`

```
00ab ??cd 00ef ??gh
```

Mask off the garbage: `n = n & 0x3333`

```
00ab 00cd 00ef 00gh
```

Shift left by 1 bit and OR: `n = n | (n << 1)`

```
0a?b 0c?d 0e?f 0g?h
```

Mask off the garbage: `n = n & 0x5555`

```
0a0b 0c0d 0e0f 0g0h
```

Now all that's left is to duplicate the bits: `n = n | (n << 1)`

```
aabb ccdd eeff gghh
```

---

This can also be done with a lookup table. The table itself is exactly 16 bytes.  Declaring it as `static const` allows the compiler to put the table in ROM. The savings in code size (fewer shifts and masking operations) typically makes up for the ROM used by the table. And the lookup method should be faster (2 lookups, 2 shifts, 1 mask, 1 OR) instead of (4 shifts, 3 masks, 4 ORs)

```
static const uint8_t table[16] = {
    0x00, 0x03, 0x0c, 0x0f, 0x30, 0x33, 0x3c, 0x3f,
    0xc0, 0xc3, 0xcc, 0xcf, 0xf0, 0xf3, 0xfc, 0xff
};

uint16_t n = 0x11;
n = (table[n >> 4] << 8) | table[n & 0xf];
printf("0x%04x\n", n);  // prints 0x0303
```

---

Fanning from 8 bits to 32 is about the same as 8-to-16, but it requires more duplication at the end:

```
uint32_t n = 0x46;
n = (n | (n << 12)) & 0x000f000f;
n = (n | (n <<  6)) & 0x03030303;
n = (n | (n <<  3)) & 0x11111111;
n = (n | (n << 1));
n = (n | (n << 2));
printf("0x%08x\n", n);  // prints 0x0f000ff0
```

At alternative method of duplicating the bits (suggested by [@wim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2439725/wim)) in the comments is to replace

```
n = (n | (n << 1));
n = (n | (n << 2));
```

with

```
n = (n << 4) - n;
```

---

Fanning from 16 bits to 32 requires an extra shift-and-mask step:

```
uint32_t n = 0x137f;
n = (n | (n << 8)) & 0x00ff00ff;
n = (n | (n << 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f;
n = (n | (n << 2)) & 0x33333333;
n = (n | (n << 1)) & 0x55555555;
n = (n | (n << 1));
printf("0x%08x\n", n);  // prints 0x030f3fff
```

Comment: This exactly what I thought :) , but I hadn't have time to write it down right, as you did. Note that instead of `n = (n | (n << 1)); n = (n | (n << 2));`, you can use: `n = (n << 4) - n;`. It is just multiplication by 15.

Comment: @wim True, that seems to work. I had to think about it a little bit because the `(n << 4)` shifts the most-significant-bit off the end of the number.

Comment: @user3386109 This is even more efficient than what I had before. I decided for the solution with lookup table, since constant values must be stored in ROM anyway and the lut can be used efficiently for both 16 to 32 and 8 to 32 bit fan out. In case anyone is interested, have a look at a minimal example: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a94c693e4de82fb

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 8-bits per byte. 2's complement arch.

This is what I started with:

```
uint32_t Eight_To_Sixteen(const uint8_t source)
{

    uint32_t result = (source & 1);
    result |= ((source & 2) << 1);        
    result |= ((source & 4) << 2);
    result |= ((source & 8) << 3);
    result |= ((source & 0x10) << 4);
    result |= ((source & 0x20) << 5);
    result |= ((source & 0x40) << 6);
    result |= ((source & 0x80) << 7);
    return (result | (result << 1));
}
```

The above isn't bad. Notice how it folds the result over with itself to duplicate all the bits.

And then I started to compare with a 2-bit table lookup approach:

```
uint32_t Eight_To_Sixteen(const uint8_t source)
{
    static const int table[] = { 0, 3, 0xc, 0xf };
    uint32_t result = table[(source & 0x03)];
    result |= (table[(source & 0x0c)>>2]) << 4;
    result |= (table[(source & 0x30) >> 4]) << 8;
    result |= (table[(source & 0xc0) >> 6]) << 12;
    return result;
}
```

Still benchmarking, but the latter is generating far less code.  You could expand it to have a larger lookup table and support wider inputs.

Comment: @user3386109 - I think the OP changed his question with that requirement after I wrote my answer. In any case, I have some adjusted proposals.

Comment: Tanks for the answer, @selbie! I slightly modified your code (see https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=492cd5e87c6f1400) so that perfectly fits my use case.